# Angular router does not react to child of child route

Tags: angular

I have the following router:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        // allowed for user with token
        path: 'admin', component: AdminMainComponent,
        canActivate: [authGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'products',
                component: AdminProductListComponent,
                children: [
                    {path: 'create', component: AdminCreateProductComponent},
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'categories',
                component: CategoryListComponent,
                children: [
                    {path: 'create', component: CreateCategoryComponent}
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

   ... 
];
```

When I visit `/admin/products/create` I see the content of `AdminProductListComponent`. The same problem is with categories. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child routes are rendered within their parent component.  This means the parent component must contain a `<router-outlet/>` in order for its child components to be rendered.

With your route config above the template of `AdminProductListComponent` must contain a `<router-outlet/>` for its children (`AdminCreateProductComponent`).

If `AdminCreateProductComponent` is not meant to be rendered within `AdminProductListComponent`, you should define them as siblings under the common "products" path:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', 
    component: AdminMainComponent,
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'products',
        children: [
          { path: '',       component: AdminProductListComponent   },
          { path: 'create', component: AdminCreateProductComponent },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'categories',
        children: [
          { path: '',       component: CategoryListComponent   },
          { path: 'create', component: CreateCategoryComponent },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Notice the "products" and "categories" paths do not specify a `component`, so the parent component would be `AdminMainComponent`.

---

You could also eliminate the intermediate path and declare all your routes as direct children of "admin":

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', 
    component: AdminMainComponent,
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'products',          component: AdminProductListComponent   },
      { path: 'products/create',   component: AdminCreateProductComponent },
      { path: 'categories',        component: CategoryListComponent       },
      { path: 'categories/create', component: CreateCategoryComponent     },
    ]
  },
];
```